# How to prevent mobile device font scale

Tags: html, css, cordova, webview, accessibility

On Android devices there is a setting that allows users to control Font Size where a user can set the font-size to "Very Large" resulting in something like this

[image]

Is there a way I can set a max font size or something like that. I know its for Accessibility purpose but this is wrecking the site.

Comment: Well those people who depend on it think the opposite and most likely find it resourceful. It won't 'wreck' the site for those users. Focusing on a responsive solution can be a simple fix, but it's hard to say, and obviously not within the scope of the question to ask for code. Just by the looks of that I think a simple flex properties additions/alterations could get you close to a desired result. As someone affected by these features, I find usability to be a priority over appeasing me aesthetically. Shouldn't take that away from me just to make it 'look' better for people who *don't* use it

Comment: @soulshined gets a +1

Comment: use media query for that we can usily done with media query

Comment: Yep, @soulshined has it right. The phone belongs to the user, and the browser should respect the user's preferences over the developer.

Comment: It seems to me the problem isn't the font size, rather it's the uneven layout of the white card containers. So, instead of seeking to limit font size, the question should be: how can we make the card layout more robust in this scenario where the user has chosen a large font? Fix the white card container height instead. The answer may lie in CSS Flexbox or Grid properties.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @soulshined and so I have redesigned my UI to be a little more forgiving to the System Font changes. Here is what I have

[image]

This layout allows the layout to not break when the system font is set to HUGE.

TLDR: There is no way to avoid these kind of situations, just design your UI to work around it.

Comment: Actually your SITE had an accessibility issue, if it doesn't support that zoom factor. It's not a work-around, you fixed your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you have already completely resolved your issue.
I'm facing with this issue in our new projects. I found an interesting thing that:
If I set `display: <an inline related type>` (for example: `display: inline-block`) for texts that are impacted by System Font Size, that texts will not be impacted anymore.